# Differential equation $y''(x)+Ay'(x)+B\cos(y(x))=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Is there an analytical solution to this equation? If so, how can I achieve it? I would like to learn a bit about the process but not being in the field makes finding resources a little harder.
$$y''(x)+Ay'(x)+B\cos(y(x))=0$$
I would like to hear some tips how I should start solving it, please do not provide the solution. Thanks!

I tried to use the $y(x)=e^{\lambda x}$ - bad idea.

I also tried to write $\cos(y(x))$ as ${\rm Re}[e^{iy(x)}]$ - still couldn't see the next step

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Shaun noted! I fixed the question.

Comment: This is a pendulum equation, seen from the side. With a friction term, so it will oscillate to the rest point at $-\frac\pi2$. Without friction, there is a solution formula that essentially uses a normalized solution, scaled to the general case. With friction a symbolic solution seems even less likely.

Comment: @LutzLehmann would it help if I want the solution for small angles around $-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Of course you can, using $\sin \phi\approx \phi$ or $\cos(y)=\sin(\frac\pi2+y)\approx\frac\pi2+y$.